# How to prevent my users from explicitly surfing to /.../index.php?

Tags: apache, directoryindex

How do I configure Apache to prevent my users from explicitly surfing to `http://myurl/somepath/index.php`
' Having `index.php` attached to the end of the URL looks ugly, to say the least.

Comment: use mod-rewrite in the Apache config or .htaccess files.  But really, if some of your users want to type in the `/index.php` path, how does it harm anyone? They obviously like it and it's not affecting anyone else.

Comment: It's ugly and I'm a paranoid freak. When I used to be a Windows developer, being a paranoid freak was actually regarded as _good_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried URL Rewriting? I am not a PHP dev, however I do know that at least in ASP.NET you can setup URL Rewriting at the server level, as well as code level (on individual pages).